# How do I create a script to run 2 commands in 2 different windows?

Tags: windows, shell-script

I have an app that uses Flask on the backend and React on the frontend.

All my app files are under C:/Users/moonman239/Documents/App

My Flask app is in one directory, and my React app is in another directory. In my Flask directory, I start the Flask app server using the command "python -m flask run" In the React app's directory, I start the React app server using the command "set https=true&&npm start".

I'd like to create a Command Prompt shell script that runs both commands.

How would I do that?

Comment: Either use the full path to each directory, or use `cd` to change from one folder tp the other.

Comment: you want to use `start` command which can pop open a new window to run a batch script of your choosing.  see  https://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntstart.php

Answer (score 0):

Create a new txt file and copy/paste this inside:

```
cd "C:/Enter/Your/Path/Here" && python -m flask run && cd "C:/Enter/Your/Path/Here" && set https=true&&npm start
```

Rename the .txt extension to .bat

Double click the .bat file to launch and it should run both commands